# Persist opendirect URLs from cold start android and iOS

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, react-native, deep-linking

I'm able to get opendirect URLs into the app on both android and iOS and they deeplink as expected when the app is in the background, however, these urls don't persist when the app is killed. I'm sure there's a configuration mismatch somewhere, but I'm not a native app developer and I am using the react-native mobile SDK, so I may have missed some necessary configuration.

Here's the relevant code I'm using in my AppDelegate.m, I can provide more if you believe it to be necessary:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"MyApp"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  // MARKETING CLOUD START

  MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder *mcsdkBuilder = [MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder new];
  [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setApplicationId:@"myApplicationId"];
  [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setAccessToken:@"myAccessToken"];
  [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setMid:@"myMID"];
  [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setAnalyticsEnabled:@(YES)];
  [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setPiAnalyticsEnabled:@(YES)];
  [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setLocationEnabled:@(YES)];
  [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setInboxEnabled:@(YES)];
  [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setMarketingCloudServerUrl:@"marketingCloudURL"];

  NSError *error = nil;
  BOOL success =
      [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_configureWithDictionary:[mcsdkBuilder sfmc_build]
                                                                 error:&error];

  if (success == YES) {
    [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_addTag:@"myApp"];
    [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setURLHandlingDelegate:self];

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (@available(iOS 10, *)) {
            // set the UNUserNotificationCenter delegate - the delegate must be set here in
            // didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        } else {
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 100000
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings
                settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                                 UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                      categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
#endif
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
      });
  } else {
      //  MarketingCloudSDK sfmc_configure failed
      os_log_debug(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "MarketingCloudSDK sfmc_configure failed with error = %@",
                   error);
  }
  return YES;
}

/ MARKETING CLOUD START

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setDeviceToken:deviceToken];
    NSLog(@"Did register for remote notifications with token: %@", [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_deviceToken]);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    os_log_debug(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError = %@", error);
}

// The method will be called on the delegate when the user responded to the notification by opening
// the application, dismissing the notification or choosing a UNNotificationAction. The delegate
// must be set before the application returns from applicationDidFinishLaunching:.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
    didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
             withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
    // tell the MarketingCloudSDK about the notification
    [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setNotificationRequest:response.notification.request];

    if (completionHandler != nil) {
        completionHandler();
    }
}

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:
             (void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@", notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
                      UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

// This method is REQUIRED for correct functionality of the SDK.
// This method will be called on the delegate when the application receives a silent push

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
          fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"did recieve remote notification");
    [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setNotificationUserInfo:userInfo];

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}


// Handle links received as Universal Links when the app is already installed.
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options];
}

- (void)sfmc_handleURL:(NSURL *)url type:(NSString *)type {
  NSLog(@"Handling open direct url coming from Marketing Cloud, type: %@", type);
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
  [appDelegate application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:dict];
}
```

Below is the configuration I'm using for Android in the MainApplication.java file, this does not directly match up with the [example here in Kotlin](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html), but I found it from another post on Stack Exchange as I believe it used to be published when java code was available:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);

    MarketingCloudSdk.init(this,
        MarketingCloudConfig.builder().setApplicationId("myApplicationId)
            .setAccessToken("myAccessToken").setSenderId("mySenderId")
            .setMarketingCloudServerUrl("marketingCloudServerUrl")
            .setMid("myMid").setNotificationCustomizationOptions(
                NotificationCustomizationOptions.create(R.drawable.ic_notification, (context, notificationMessage) -> {
                  int requestCode = new Random().nextInt();

                  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(notificationMessage.url())) {
                    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode,
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(notificationMessage.url())),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                  }

                  return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class),
                      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                }, (context, notificationMessage) -> {
                  return NotificationManager.createDefaultNotificationChannel(context);
                }))
            .build(this),
        status -> Log.e("INIT", status.toString()));

    MarketingCloudSdk.requestSdk(sdk -> {
      RegistrationManager registrationManager = sdk.getRegistrationManager();
      registrationManager.edit().addTags("MyApp");
    });
  }
```

I believe my question to be very closely related to [this post here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/347080/universal-links-not-working-when-attached-in-a-push-notification-with-app-killed/347214#347214?newreg=506dfdcc38224bd488df32ed4bea244e). I'm unfortunately unable to respond to the authors post due to low reputation points, so I'm creating this separate issue with more context on my problem. The reason I can't implement the above is I'm unable to get the payload structure of the links in order to test that out, since for me I can't get push notifications unless I deploy the iOS builds through testflight, and then I can't log them locally. Android I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Open a support ticket.

Comment: Also, `MyApp` will never be added to Tags if you don't call `commit()`.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I opened a ticket a while back (ticket #41377706) and I was told the following:
"Thanks for sharing your time and patience on the call as discussed we in developer support currently abide by "Break and Fix" mechanism hence to best address your implementation assistance I shall provide the details of your Account Executive and they shall incline you with the professional services team on our side."

Comment: This was after I had a WebEx call with a development support agent. In the response message I was also told this:
"Salesforce Mobile SDK is open-source product. Because mobile SDK development can be unique, we ask customers to please post specific inquiries and questions using the < mobilesdk > tag on the Salesforce Stack Exchange site". That's why I tried posting here as well.

Comment: I know this is painful, but I suggest you open another support case.  I do not know how you ended up talking with the `Salesforce Mobile SDK` support :(. Be explicit that your issue is with the `Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDK` (which is not open source) ;)

Comment: Okay, thank you for following up!

Comment: If it starts going down the wrong path again, have them at-mention me.